# Parsing その事に見られるようす

Tags: grammar

One of the definitions of 事柄,

> その事に見られるようす

I'm bit confused with this sentence. Is その事に見られる modifying ようす? What's the role of に here? What conjugation is 見られる? Is it interchangeable with 見える?

Comment: It's either passive form or potential form. 見える means "visible" whereas 見られる as a potential form is more like "given the opportunity to see", as I understand it. I don't understand the other part of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The phrase itself

Considering the context (as a short phrase serving as a sense definition for 事柄【ことがら】), we would have to parse this as a noun phrase, wherein the parts to the left qualify (modify) that noun.  So the core or "head" term in this phrase is [よ]{●}[う]{●}[す]{●}.

Here's that line deconstructed:

- 事柄 = その事に見られる[よ]{●}[う]{●}[す]{●}
  What is a *kotogara*?  A *kotogara* is a kind of *yōsu*:
  事柄 = 　　　　　　　　[よ]{●}[う]{●}[す]{●}
  But what kind of *yōsu* are we talking about?  We have to look at the part to the left of the word, the part that describes what kind of *yōsu* we have.  The kind that:
  　　     その事にみられる

Let's look at this word-by-word.

- その事に見られるようす →
- [その]{that}[事]{fact, thing, circumstance  }[に]{  PART: "in"  }[見られる]{  PASSIVE: "be seen"  }[ようす]{  state; manner; look; kind; characteristic}

Reading this phrase more-or-less backwards to arrive at the English ordering of concepts, we get:

- The characteristic seen in that thing / circumstance.

#### Your specific questions

> Is その事に見られる modifying ようす?

Yes.  See above.

> What's the role of に here?

See above.  With a passive verb like 見られる, the に *could* be marking the agent (the do-er) of the verb (translatable as *"by"*, as in *"something done **by** someone"*), but that interpretation just doesn't make any sense in this context.  に can also mark location where motion is going, or where a thing or quality exists (translatable as *"to"*, or *"at"* or *"in"* or "*on*", as in *"we go **to** the store"* or *"it's **on** the table"* or *"there is red **in** this"*), and it's this latter sense that fits the context best.

> What conjugation is 見られる? Is it interchangeable with 見える?

見られる here must be the passive.  In this case, it's not interchangeable with 見える, since the passive sense is needed instead of the potential.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can you be sure that 見られる is passive not 自発 like 見える?

Comment: @EricHammond, simply because the potential doesn’t make sense here.

Comment: @EricHammond - It's possible to interpret this 見られる as indicating potentiality as in "the characteristic one **can** see in that thing" but it's still not interchangeable with 見える as その事に見えるようす would mean something like "the way in which (something) looks to be that thing."